# using shared dockerfile for multiple dockerfiles

Tags: python, docker, go, kubernetes, dockerfile

What I have, are multi similar and simple `dockerfile`s

But what I want is to have a single base `dockerfile` and my `dockerfile`s
pass their variables into it.

In my case the only difference between `dockerfile`s are
simply their `EXPOSE`, so I think it's better to keep a base `dockerfile` and other `dockerfile`s only inject that variables into base `dockerfile` like a template engine

A sample `dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /bin/app ./cmd/root.go

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /bin/
COPY --from=builder /bin/app .
EXPOSE 8080
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source="https://github.com/mohammadne/bookman-auth"
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/app"]
CMD ["server", "--env=dev"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as yasen said, it's impossible to have import directive.

finally what I have did is as follow: [link to github repository](https://github.com/mohammadne/bookman)

1. create a template text file with `EXPOSE ${{ EXPOSED_PORT }}`:

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go mod download && make ent-generate

RUN go build -o /bin/app ./cmd/root.go

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /bin/

COPY --from=builder /bin/app .

EXPOSE ${{ EXPOSED_PORT }}

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source="https://github.com/mohammadne/bookman-library"

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/app"]

CMD ["server", "--env=dev"]
```

2. and then create a python script

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from shutil import copyfile
import os


class Config:
    def __init__(self, service, port):
        self.service = service
        self.port = port


configs = [
    Config("auth", "8080"),
    Config("user", "8081"),
    Config("library", "8082"),
]

pathToDir = "../build"
template = f"{pathToDir}/template.txt"

for config in configs:
    outputDir = f"{pathToDir}/{config.service}"
    os.mkdir(outputDir)

    fileName = copyfile(template, f"{outputDir}/Dockerfile")

    with open(fileName, "rt") as file:
        replacedText = file.read().replace('${{ EXPOSED_PORT }}', config.port)

    with open(fileName, "wt") as file:
        file.write(replacedText)
```

then in the python script you can replace your patterns !!!

Answer (score 5):

## `IMPORT` directive will never be implemented

A long time ago there was proposed `IMPORT` directive for `Docker`

Unfortunately, issues are closed while PR's are still open:

- [docker - using shared dockerfile for multiple dockerfiles - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234878/using-shared-dockerfile-for-multiple-dockerfiles)
- [Proposal: Dockerfile add INCLUDE · Issue #735 · moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/735)
- [implement an INCLUDE verb/instruction for docker build files · Issue #974 · moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/974)
- [Add INCLUDE feature · Issue #40165 · moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40165)
- [docker build: initial work on the include command by flavio · Pull Request #2108 · moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/2108)
- [Dockerfile templating to automate image creation](https://www.isaac.nl/en/developer-blog/dockerfile-templating-to-automate-image-creation/index.html)
- [Templating your Dockerfile like a boss! | by Ahmed ElGamil | Dockbit](https://blog.dockbit.com/templating-your-dockerfile-like-a-boss-2a84a67d28e9)

## Solution for your case

But for your case, all you need - is just a bit of `sed`

E.g.:

```
# Case1: inplace templating
EXPOSED_PORT=8081 sed -i "s/EXPOSE 8080/EXPOSE $EXPOSED_PORT/" Dockerfile

# Case2: generating Dockerfile from template
sed "s/EXPOSE 8080/EXPOSE $EXPOSED_PORT/" Dockerfile.template > Dockerfile
```

Explanation:

- `EXPOSED_PORT=8081` declares local `bash` variable
- `sed` is a tool for text manipulation
- `sed -i "s/EXPOSE 8080/EXPOSE $EXPOSED_PORT/" Dockerfile` replaces `EXPOSE 8080` to `EXPOSE 8081`
- `sed "s/EXPOSE 8080/EXPOSE $EXPOSED_PORT/" Dockerfile.template > Dockerfile` generates the new `Dockerfile` from `Dockerfile.template`

Comment: can this be done cross-platform way? what is the windows command for sed?

Answer (score 4):

You can have the exposed port as a build argument for the image. If you make a dockerfile like this

```
FROM alpine:latest
ARG EXPOSED_PORT
EXPOSE ${EXPOSED_PORT}
```

You can specify which port is exposed when you build it by passing the port number like this

```
docker build -t myimage --build-arg EXPOSED_PORT=8000 .
```

It's worth noting that the EXPOSE statement mainly is documentation. Your image will work the same without the EXPOSE statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very good idea.  I have two thoughts:

1. Create the base dockerfile as you described and then build it like this:  `docker image build tag base`.  Then you can have two liner Dockerfiles that look like `FROM base \n EXPOSE 8080`
2. Alternatively you can have a single Dockerfile and just change the way you run the containers.  There is an `expose` switch.  Just about anything you specify in the Dockerfile can be overriden in the `run` command.